# Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-2

This is my html code:

```
<span>
<%if (Model.Data.Service.Attachments.Count > 0)
{

%><h3>Downloads for your service:</h3> <%

foreach (var attach in Model.Data.Service.Attachments)
{
    %><%=attach.Name%>: https://<%= Request.Url.Host%> "/File/Download/" <%= attach.Id.ToString()%><br />
}<%

}%></span>
```

The error is saying that I am missing a "{" but I dont believe that is what is going on here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing brace of your foreach isn't in a <% %> block.  It needs to be:

```
<span>
<%if (Model.Data.Service.Attachments.Count > 0)
{

%><h3>Downloads for your service:</h3> <%

foreach (var attach in Model.Data.Service.Attachments)
{
%><%=attach.Name%>: https://<%= Request.Url.Host%> "/File/Download/" <%= attach.Id.ToString()%><br />
<% }

}%></span>
```

Or to make it a bit neater try using string.Format instead:

```
<span>
<%if (Model.Data.Service.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
%><h3>Downloads for your service:</h3> <%
foreach (var attach in Model.Data.Service.Attachments)
{
    %><%= string.Format("{0}: https://{1}/File/Download/{2}", attach.Name, Request.Url.Host, attach.Id) %><br />
<%}
}%></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

> but I dont believe that is what is going on here

You'd better trust the compiler. I would recommend you properly indenting your code as such syntax errors are easily seen:

```
<span>
<% if (Model.Data.Service.Attachments.Count > 0) { %>
    <h3>Downloads for your service:</h3> 
    <% foreach (var attach in Model.Data.Service.Attachments) { %>
        <%= attach.Name %>: https://<%= Request.Url.Host %> "/File/Download/" <%= attach.Id.ToString() %>
        <br />
    <% } %>
<% } %>
</span>
```